# derivative of square root of $x_1$ and $x_2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am confusing with calculation of derivative of $$\sqrt{x_1x_2}$$ I am very thankful if anyone help me out of this problem.
my question is that,

(1) $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two different variable i just want to calculate the derivative with respect to $x$.

(2) if $x_1=x_2$ what would be the value of derivative.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't tell what's the relation between $\,x\,$ and $\,x_1,x_2\,$ then it is impossible to solve this.

Comment: x1 and x2 are the function of x.

Comment: Do you mean $\;x= x_1\cdot x_2\;$ or **each** is a function *of* $\,x\,$ ?

Comment: Each is a function of x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok then: so $\,x_i=x_i(x)\;,\;i=1,2\,$ , and then:

$$\frac d{dx}\left(\sqrt{x_1x_2}\right)=\frac{x_1' x_2}{2\sqrt{x_1x_2}}+\frac{x_1x_2'}{2\sqrt{x_1x_2}}=\frac{x_1'x_2+x_1x_2'}{2\sqrt{x_1x_2}}$$